# How to search in multiple columns on same table? (fat free framework)

Tags: fat-free-framework

I need to search same query on multiple columns using fatfree.
This works correctly on one column:

```
 $f3->set('list', $users->find(array('name LIKE ?','%'.$queries.'%')));
```

However, if I try:

```
 $f3->set('list', $users->find(array('name, email LIKE ?','%'.$queries.'%')));
```

I get error:

```
PDOStatement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' email LIKE '%invent%'' at line 1
```

How can I do this?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```php
$f3->set('list', $users->find(array(
  'name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ?',
  '%'.$queries.'%',
  '%'.$queries.'%'
)));
```

NB: PDO doesn't allow to use a same placeholder twice so you have to give twice the same argument (`'%'.$queries.'%'`).